# No indent in modified \maketitle in article

Tags: indentation, titles, article

I am looking to have the title left justified along with the name of the author and teacher and the date. I have managed to get it left justified but the name is being indented, this is not what I want. Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{TITLE}

\author{
Name \textsc{Last name} \\ 
Mr. \textsc{Name}
\hspace*{-\tabcolsep}}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\let\center\flushleft
\let\endcenter\endflushleft
\maketitle
\endgroup

\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't easier to use the environment `titlepage` instead of redefining `maketitle`? BTW: `\author` is printed inside a `tabular` environment with the row `c`.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Doesn't titlepage make a new page? I want that information on the first page along with the essay.

Comment: Do you need to use `\maketitle`? If you have a one column article I think there would be not much harm if you write what you want without using `\maketitle`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`titling`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titling) package is specifically designed to alter the output of `\maketitle`. Its package documentation provides the standard definitions of `\maketitle` on page 2, so we just need to alter that.

Note that `\and` is the LaTeX way of introducing several authors. I also added `\thanks` author footnotes just to demonstrate that they work. In order for this solution to look 100% like your code, you’ll have to add a font size command like `\large` to `\preauthor`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{titling}

%% Standard `article' settings:
%\pretitle{\begin{center}\LARGE}
%\posttitle{\par\end{center}\vskip 0.5em}
%\preauthor{\begin{center}
%\large \lineskip 0.5em%
%\begin{tabular}[t]{c}}
%\postauthor{\end{tabular}\par\end{center}}
%\predate{\begin{center}\large}
%\postdate{\par\end{center}}

%% Adapted settings:
\pretitle{\begin{flushleft}\LARGE}
\posttitle{\par\end{flushleft}\vskip 0.5em}
\preauthor{\begin{flushleft}}
\postauthor{\end{flushleft}}
\predate{\begin{flushleft}\large}
\postdate{\par\end{flushleft}}

% Change \and to \newline (originally, it basically starts a new column
\renewcommand{\and}{\newline}

\title{TITLE}
\author{
Name \textsc{Last name}\thanks{Foo} \and Mr. \textsc{Name}\thanks{Bar}
}

\usepackage[paperheight=12cm]{geometry}% just for the demo
\begin{document}
\maketitle

Hello World.
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: I think some `%` characters are missing

Comment: @egreg Where? filler

Comment: `\author{%` and also at the end of the author list.

Comment: @egreg I was considering that, but it doesn’t seem to result in any difference here? This does make sense to me – usually, spaces at the beginning and end of a paragraph don’t matter either.

Comment: This is by chance, precisely because you're doing `\begin{flushleft}`.

Comment: @doncherry Is it possible to have the name and date, double spaced and then title which is centred?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `titling` package for formatting the title. Alternatively, you can redefine the `\maketitle` command from scratch to get what you want; here is an example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{An outline of intellectual rubbish}
\author{Bertrand Russell}

\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
\newpage
\null
\vskip 2em%
\begin{flushleft}%
\let \footnote \thanks
{\LARGE \@title \par}%
\vskip 1.5em%
{\large
\lineskip .5em%
\noindent
\@author\par}
\vskip 1em%
{\large \@date}%
\end{flushleft}
\par
\vskip 1.5em}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: I added an answer using `titling`.

Answer (score 2):

The command `\author` is executed in a `tabular` environment with column type `c`

So you can patch the definition to change the tabular by `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\begin{tabular}[t]{c}}{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{center}{flushleft}{}{}%patches \begin{center}
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{center}{flushleft}{}{}%patches \end{center}
\makeatother
\title{TITLE}

\author{%
Name \textsc{Last name} \\ 
Mr. \textsc{Name}
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

However a simple usage of

```
\begin{flushleft}
\Large TITLE \\[2\baselineskip]

\large Name \textsc{Last name} \\ 
Mr. \textsc{Name} \\[1\baselineskip]

\today
\end{flushleft}
```

works too.

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{TITLE}

%\author{
%Name \textsc{Last name} \\ 
%Mr. \textsc{Name}
%\hspace*{-\tabcolsep}}


\makeatletter


\renewcommand\maketitle{\begin{titlepage}%
  \let\footnotesize\small
  \let\footnoterule\relax
  \let \footnote \thanks
  \null\vfil
  \vskip 60\p@
  \begin{center}%
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 3em%
    {\large
     \lineskip .75em%
%     \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
     \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
      \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large \@date \par}%       % Set date in \large size.
  \end{center}\par
  \@thanks
  \vfil\null
  \end{titlepage}%
}  
 \makeatother


\author{%
Name \textsc{Last name}\\ 
%\hspace*{-2cm}
Mr. \textsc{Name}
%\hspace*{-\tabcolsep}
}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\let\center\flushleft
\let\endcenter\endflushleft
\maketitle
\endgroup

\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}`
```

Comment: You completely redefine `\maketitle`. Then you can replace `center` by `flushleft` and you dont need: `\let\center\flushleft\let\endcenter\endflushleft`

Comment: @Marco Daniel: Certainly. It was only an illustration, where the indentation of \@author is controlled.